# VBA, Excel: How to pass a class object to a form

Tags: vba, object, parameters, userform

How do I pass a class object from ThisWorkbook to a UserForm?

I receive the error noted below:

In **ThisWorkbook**:

```
Dim MainObject As MyClass
Set MainObject = New MyClass

Public Sub ShowMyForm()
  Dim frmMyForm as MyForm
  Set frmMyForm = New MyForm
  frmMyForm.FormObject = MainObject  ' *<-- Run-time Error '13': Type mismatch*
End Sub
```

In **MyForm**:

```
Private p_Object As MyClass

Property Get FormObject() As MyClass
  Set FormObject = p_Object
End Property

Property Set FormObject(ByRef Value As MyClass)
  Set p_Object = Value
End Property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are assigning objects you need to use the Set keyword, like this:

```
Set frmMyForm.FormObject = MainObject
```